# Replace and Add Wrapper with Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting with some date that I cannot format the way I want, so I'm trying to format via javaScript.

```
<div class="date">
Oct. 07,
</div>
```

And I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div class="date">
<div class="m1">Oct</div> <div class="m2">07</div>
</div>
```

I have this jQuery, but I'm not close yet

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.date').each(function( index ) {
var kill = $(this).html().replace(/. /g, ' ').replace(/,/g,' ');
$(this).html(kill);
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.date').html(function (idx, html) {
    return html.replace(/([a-z]+).(\s+)(\d+),/i, '<div class="m1">$1</div> <div class="m2">$3</div>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CgZSg/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $date = $('.date'),
    text = $date.text(),
    monthYear = text.split('.');
$date.html('')
    .append($('<div class="m1">' + monthYear[0] + '</div>'))
    .append($('<div class="m2">' + monthYear[1].replace(',','') + '</div>'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksoncan34/LH9pj/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too

```
var date = $.trim($('.date').text()), d = date.split('.');
$('.date').html("<div class='m1'>"+d[0]+"</div> <div class='m2'>"+d[1].replace(',', '')+"</div>");
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/rqmrU/)